# Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[[Integer]]

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and have a question about types, it error out because it couldn't match expected type. I believe `squarePrime` is a bool, correct me if i'm wrong and it is complaining because it wants a `int`? Can someone explain, thanks in advance.

```
squarePrimes n =  [n^2 | (n) <- [2..n-1], (all (\a -> mod n a /= 0) [2..n-1])]
multiOfFive a = mod a 5 == 0 

fun n = [n | n <-[1..n], multiOfFive || squarePrimes n]
```

Comment: This question looks like a near duplicate of this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59781958/126014

Comment: Have you tried interacting with those functions in GHCi? Have you tried using GHCi's `:type` command to see what the types are?

Answer (score 4):

The 'squarePrimes n' function returns a list of Integers, as opposed to a Bool or a list of Bools. Looking at the list comprehension:

```
[n^2 | (n) <- [2..n-1], (all (\a -> mod n a /= 0) [2..n-1])]
```

This will produce a list of n^2, of n pulled from the range [2..n-1], for every n that satisfies the condition:

```
(all (\a -> mod n a /= 0) [2..n-1])
```

Then, in the list comprehension used in the definition of 'fun':

```
[n | n <-[1..n], multiOfFive || squarePrimes n]
```

A list is being constructed of each n in the range 1 to n, as long as the following condition is true:

```
multiOfFive || squarePrimes n
```

Haskell is expecting this to evaluate to a Bool. However, 'multiOfFive' is being called without any argument, and 'squarePrimes n' returns a list of Integers, as opposed to a Bool.

Without knowing exactly what the intention of 'fun n' is, I have altered the provided code a little bit to get a list comprehension that loads without error:

```
fun n = [n | n <- [1..n], (multiOfFive n) || (elem n (squarePrimes n))]
```

Now, it uses the 'elem' function to check whether a given 'n' is an element of the list 'squarePrimes n'.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe `squarePrimes` is a Bool, correct me if I'm wrong

GHCi will tell you:

```hs
λ> let squarePrimes n = [n^2 | (n) <- [2..n-1], (all (\a -> mod n a /= 0) [2..n-1])]
λ> :t squarePrimes 
squarePrimes :: Integral a => a -> [a]
```

> It is complaining because it wants an `int`? Can someone explain

Here `Integral i => i` is any integer type. That could for example be `Int` or `Integer`. This is because the integer literals `0`, `1`, `2` and the arithmetic operators you use aren't restricted to a specific integer type.

You're using `squarePrimes n` as a `Bool`.

You're also using `multiOfFive` as a `Bool` when its type is:

```hs
λ> let multiOfFive a = mod a 5 == 0 
λ> :t multiOfFive 
multiOfFive :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

so a function that takes an integer type and *returns* a `Bool`.